# Control Panel in ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04, panel

can I have two different control panels running in the same ubuntu server?

Like EHCP and ISPConfig

Thx

Comment: I am looking for control panel for ubuntu 14.04, already tried ajenti and ehcp but none of them working well,please can you suggest me any nice free panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with other applications (text editors, web browsers, web servers ) I would assume you can install as many as you wish. Each (web) interface would need to be configured to use a unique port or URL.

I Just as you would not edit the same file with two different editors at the same time, I would not configure the same service with both tools at the same time. You might manage apache with one and iptables with another. If you try to, for example, manage apache with both the may or may not conflict. I could potentially see virtual hosts and/or virtualization becoming confusing if the two control panels used different configuration methods.

Comment: Thank you, i will prepare another VM with ubuntu and install ISPConfig, to make some test!